# TAR command exit status non 0, with the option ignore command error

Tags: tar, debian-stretch

I'm trying to make a tar of a logs directory, the applications are running so the logs keep changing, clearly when i run the tar command it give me the warning: 
*"file changed as we read it"*, and give an exit status of 1, the problem is that the exit status keep being non zero (1) with the options:

```
--ignore-failed-read --ignore-command-error --warning=no-file-changed
```

There's a way to force the exit status 0?

Comment: Why do you need to tar a file while it is being changed!?

Comment: @Khaled running on this machine there are critical application, I'can't stop them, and between having backup and no backup, i accept the fact that having possible corrupt backup is better than nothing

Comment: Rotate the log files immediately before the backup then backup everything bar the active log files or if you are using a filesystem that you can take snapshots of, snapshot the filesystem and backup from that.

Comment: @Emax: Any well-written application should support log rotation. It will re-open the log files upon receiving a SIGHUP. Using logrotate, you can have your log files rotated daily, weekly, etc. Logrotate can also compress the rotated files or do whatever you want.